# Oracle Weblogic datasource inactive connection timeout setting when using JdbcCursorItemReader

Tags: spring, oracle, weblogic, spring-batch

I am planning to write a **Spring Batch job** which will use [**JdbcCursorItemReader**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcCursorItemReader.html) and going to run on Oracle Weblogic app server. It’s a one step job which will read from Oracle database using JdbcCursorItemReader then process(create pdf file) and finally write to Oracle content server. It’s a chunk oriented step where JdbcCursorItemReader's fetch size is 100 and commit interval is 50. Processing of a single row going to cost me 5~10 seconds.

Now here is my concern, if JdbcCursorItemReader’s fetch size is 100, is it mean that while processing this 100 row JdbcCursorItemReader’s **connection will be in inactive state**?

If this is the case and Oracle Weblogic datasource’s Inactive connection timeout set to 60 second then whether this JdbcCursorItemReader’s connection will be **reclaimed by datasource** after 60 seconds of inactivity or not?

Comment: you are right. If the Inactive Connection Timeout property is greater than 0 your connection will be reclaimed by weblogic. Please also note that this feature is disabled by default (0)
Batch applications require specific configuration of datasource because of long running processes. The recommendation is to setup dedicated datasources for batch applications.

Comment: Thanks @Emmanuel Collin. I am planning to use separate datasource. But our weblogic system administrator is not recommending to disable inactive connection timeout.